# Setting environment values in server.env in Liberty moving from setenv.sh in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websphere-liberty

I am moving from Apache tomcat to Liberty server. In my tomcat server, I had a setenv file in which I had set the values of

```
CATALINA_OPT=" \
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$PROJECT_ROOT/log4j.properties \
-Darchs.depl.applicationId=tester"
```

I am not able to figure out what should be the corresponding setting in server.env file in Liberty.

I tried putting:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$PROJECT_ROOT/log4j.properties 
-Darchs.depl.applicationId=tester
```

When I start I get an error:

```
eval: -D: invalid option
eval: usage: eval [arg ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server.env file only supports key value pairs.

If you want to be setting JVM args, use the jvm.options file instead.

Example jvm.options syntax (from the [IBM doc](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html)):

```
# Set the maximum heap size to 1024m.
-Xmx1024m

# Set a system property.
-Dcom.ibm.example.system.property=ExampleValue

# Enable verbose output for class loading.
-verbose:class

# Enable verbose garbage collection.
-verbose:gc

# Specify an alternate verbose garbage collection log on IBM Java Virtual Machines only.
-Xverbosegclog:verbosegc.log

# Specify additional verbose garbage collection options on HotSpot Java Virtual Machines only.
-Xloggc:verbosegc.log
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
```

Locations where you can put the jvm.options file (again from the IBM doc):

> The server management script searches for jvm.options in two locations: `${wlp.install.dir}/etc/jvm.options` and `${server.config.dir}/jvm.options`. If both files are present, the options in the `${server.config.dir}/jvm.options` file are used.

Comment: where do I check what is my server.config.fir ?

Comment: my server.env file is in wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer

Comment: @user1692342 your ${server.config.dir} is the directory of your server (where the server.xml is).  In your case it is would be wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer, which is the same directory your server.env is in